# Is it normal for Azure to create a web service with the same name when creating virtual machine?

Tags: azure

I just created a windows 2012 datacenter VM in azure, however I notice in management portal that Azure also created a cloud service with same name. Is this normal?I don't want to be double charged..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal.  You are not charged for Cloud Services.  You're only charged for actual VM's deployed in them.  Cloud Service is just a record in a database and a concept that is used to group Azure resources together